# OpenJPA: @OneToMany mapping with composite primary key

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa, jpa-1.0

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
public class ParentClass implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private long parentID;

    // uni-directional many-to-one association 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Child> children;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD")
public class Child implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private ChildPK id;


   // bi-directional many-to-one association
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Parent parent;
}

@Embeddable
public class ChildPK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private int parentID;

    @Column(name = "CHILD_NM")
    private String childName;
}

 for (Child child : parentClassEntity.getParent().getChildren()) {
    child.getId().setParentID(parentID);
 }
 parentClassEntity.setParentID(parentID);
 dummyDAO.persist(parentClassEntity);
```

We are using OpenJPA 1.2 (aligned with JSR-220 Java Persistence 1.0 specification). We are also evaluating the solution with OpenJPA 2.3 (aligned with JSR-317 Java Persistence 2.0).

For persisting the child we need to call the merge and delete operations on the parent as well as child, which is leading to explicit two calls to the database.

```
entityManager.merge(parentEntity);
entityManager.merger (childEntity);
```

Since this is not automatically being taken care by openJPA and we are trying to evaluate whether OpenJPA can handle this scenario or do we need to explicitly set the values using setter methods (i.e looping thorugh all the instances of the child entities).

Any pointers or directions if can be recommended then it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: OK, couple of things. First you need to post the code you use to save these objects. We can't help you much without that. Second, don't put the `@ManyToOne` association in the `ChildPK`. The association is from `Child` to `Parent` so you should define it in `Child`. We have about 140 `EmbeddedId` classes in the 400-odd Entities that we have and we never define associations in the `Embeddable` class.

Comment: Oh, and no framework has been developed to read your mind, so yes, you need to define the references between your Entities before you persist them. So a `Child` should have a reference to it's `Parent`, and the `Parent` should have the `Child` in it's set of children (which you should name as a plural - `children` or `childSet` or `childList`).

Comment: I'm fairly sure OpenJPA 2.3 is actually implementing JPA 2.0

Comment: We are evaluating the solution for this issue by using OpenJPA 2.3 as well as OpenJPA 1.2.

Comment: @DuncanKinnear just needed to check with regarding cascading of value from parent primary key to child foreign key using mapsId. Could you please help us with the same.

Comment: Because we define the foreign key to the parent as a `@Column` and use `updatable = false` on this column, we populate the parent key ourselves. However, I understand that if the Parent references the child AND the Child references the Parent, then Hibernate can populate the keys appropriately. The key is to have bi-directional associations.